# Remove breakpoint in script

Tags: node.js, debugging

Suppose there is a file `test.js` as follow:

`var a = 1
var b = 2
debugger; // breakpoint
console.log(3)`

After launching the node debugger with: `node debug test.js`, is it possible to remove the breakpoint in script under the debugger without modifying the script?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible during execution to dynamically remove/add explicit `debugger;` statements.

As per the [debugger documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html), the only way to dynamically add/remove breakpoints is by using `setBreakpoint()` and `clearBreakpoint()` commands.